# Computer appliance protocol

Tags: protocol-design, authentication, key-exchange, replay-attack

I build the [computer appliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_appliance) system that consist of software server and multiple controllers. The system I want to build must be pluggable in the sense that when I connect a controller **C** to the network, the server **S** will immediately finds it after initial message exchange(*Step 1*). After an initiation phase both **C** and **S** start TCP servers and able to send and receive messages to each other during multiple sessions (*Step 2*) without need for repeating *Step 1* between sessions.

And now several challenges that I should to resolve

1. Prevent spoofing of **C** and/or **S** on *Step 1*
2. Prevent spoofing of **C** and/or **S** on *Step 2*
3. Prevent replay attack on *Step 2*
4. Ensure message confidentiality on *Step 2*

And here are some thougts about it:

1. I should authenticate both sides on *Step 1* to solve the first problem.
2. I should perform the key exchange on *Step 1*
3. I should encrypt all messages on *Step 2* with symmetric key that have been received while *Step 1* key exchange to solve the fourth problem.
4. I should use nonces or timestamps on *Step 2* to solve the second and third problems

---

Finally I want to ask some questions:

- Are my thoughts about solving the problems right?
- What is the best protocol for performing both authentication and key exchange at the same-time?

**EDIT**: The messages sended infrequently, so I need a lightweight protocol on *Step 2*. The protocol must be **stateful** of course to store symmetric key and possibly other auth info between sessions.

Comment: What about using a standardized protocol like TLS?

Comment: What distinguishes a real **C** from a spoofed **C** ? $\:$

Comment: Sounds like a question that's better-suited for the [IT Security site](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann, my messages sended one-by-one and infrequently so every time I need to send a message, **C** ans **S** must do the handshake, send the payload and break the connection, so if a payload is a few bytes, the TLS is too cost for me.